# Retro games: scaling all sprites or rather the entire canvas?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I’ve tried my best searching online and reading the documentation to find a good answer, but I have yet to find one.

I’m creating a multi-platform 2d side-scrolling retro game in Cocos2d-x v3. The engine is rather new to me, but I do have decent experience in C++, Xcode and game development.

The game which I’m trying to create is utilising super minimal pixel art and I’m at a loss as to decide which approach would be best. Currently I have two ideas:

1. Work with a fixed resolution (e.a. 240x120, I’m working with
   really(!) small sprites) and use Design Resolution to scale the entire canvas
   upwards to the screen size using kResolutionNoBorder.

   - Pros: I don’t have to scale my sprites and I can just use a short piece of code in the Init() function.
   - Cons: Not sure if you can use Design Resolution to scale pixel perfect?
2. Scale every sprite so that it appears to be running on a ±240x120
   resolution.

   - Pros: ?
   - Cons: I have to scale every sprite which means more code and less clarity as to what is really happening on my canvas.

I read the multi-resolution-support page on the Cocos2d-x wiki, but it didn’t really give me advice on what would be the best approach for retro games.

I feel that I don’t have enough knowledge about Cocos2d-x to make the right decision yet, and a voice in my head says I’m forgetting something important.

Comment: If you're not sure you can do "pixel-perfect" scaling for the entire canvas after the scene is rendered, what makes you think you can perfectly scale your sprites individually?

Answer (score 1):

There are more factors at play. How do want the game to look that are diffrent from 240*120.

I'll suggest scaling the screen for pixel art games. You can also control aliasing/anti aliasing param for all texture. Generally for pixel game, anti aliasing is turned off.

KResolutionNoBorder might crop your game edges to fit it in. There are other options,like kResolutuonFixedHeight, kResoltuionFitAll, depending to game requirement and HUD placement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it still can look pixel perfect in large screen, cocos2dx uses `float` for the size and position, so even if 1 pixel in your design view is represented as `5x5 pixels` on the screen, when you move the position `0.2 point` it will look like it moves `1 pixel`. How precise it can be depends on the device screen resolution.

I would go for scaling the canvas